# Why is there an alternate Superman meets Lex Luthor underground scene?

Tags: alternate-version, superman

When Superman the Movie came out and later on TV, when Superman first meets up with Lex Luthor in Luthor's underground lair, Superman passes through several tests.  He gets shot at, fire, cold, and maybe something else I don't remember.  He breaks down a giant steel door at the end.  Modern versions only have the door part.

Whenever it comes on TV or even in uncut versions on DVD (or CVR for that matter) the scene is missing.  How come?  I loved that scene.

Comment: Much better answer at http://movies.stackexchange.com/a/893/23541

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a deleted scene. It's not an alternative - it simply extends the sequence beginning with Superman tunnelling through the pavement and ending with him breaking through the door of Luthor's lair.

Certain cuts of this film for television broadcast include this, as does the 'Expanded Edition' of Superman The Movie, included with 'The Superman Motion Picture Anthology' and other special edition releases of the film on DVD and Blu-ray.